# Can I say "Google for it" if I'm using another search engine?

Tags: word-usage

It seems like many American dramas use the phrase a lot. Suppose I'm using Bing (from Microsoft), do I need to use "look it up on the internet" or something else?

Comment: Your question in-text and your question in the title can invite opposite answers; please edit them to be consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *[to google](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/google)*  is used also as a generic term for internet searching.

> 1) verb (used with object), Goo·gled, Goo·gling.
>   (often lowercase)
>
> to search the Internet for information about (a person, topic, etc.):
>
> - We googled the new applicant to check her background.
>
> 2) verb (used without object), Goo·gled, Goo·gling.
>   (often lowercase)
>
> to use a search engine such as Google to find information, a website address, etc., on the Internet.

(Dictionary.com)

> A number of common words began as trademarks but passed over into unprotectable generic terms. Aspirin, for one. And escalator. And cellophane. Dry ice. Thermos. Trampoline. For some of those, there are other words we could use for the product, but it's easy to see why we prefer to call it "aspirin" rather than "acetylsalicylic acid." For others, the term is so ingrained that it's hard to think of what else we would call the product.

([www.stites.com](https://www.stites.com/resources/trademarkology/is-google-generic-if-only-there-were-a-way-to-search-for-the-answer-on-the-internet))

Comment: Another trademark that has entered the vernacular as a generic verb - in spite of ongoing eforts by the corporate trademark owner to stop it - is "xerox".

Answer (score 2):

Note that the usual phrase in English is, "Google something", not "Google for something".